# VBA run time '1004' error when connected via VPN

Tags: vba, vpn

I've searched through several forums and have found similar questions, but not my specific problem.

I have a macro that saves the active workbook to the specific user's folder, and saves a dated, xlsx, version in a sub folder. My macro-enable workbook is used by both in-office and remote associates. The in-office associates have no issue using this macro to save & archive the workbook to their folder, and, up until last week, the remote associates using VPN had no issues either.

However, over the past few days the remote associates using VPN have been receiving an error like `run time error '1004': The specified dimensions are not valid for the current chart type` and the code hangs on the `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` line at the end. Why would this error be coming up for a `.SaveAs` issue? I'm at a loss.

```
MainPath = "O:\Revenue Management\Centralized Revenue Management Service\CRMS Hotels\"
sPathSeek = MainPath & strPropNo & "*"
sFile = Dir(sPathSeek, vbDirectory)
sFileCheck = MainPath & sFile & "\Strategy Pack"
sBuildHist = MainPath & sFile & "\Strategy Pack\" & year1 & "\"
filePath = MainPath & sFile & "\Strategy Pack\" & propNo & " Strategy Pack.xlsm"
histPath = MainPath & sFile & "\Strategy Pack\" & year1 & "\" & propNo & " Strategy Pack " & STRdate & ".xlsx"
iLength = Len(Dir(sFileCheck, vbDirectory))
iLength2 = Len(Dir(sBuildHist, vbDirectory))

If iLength = 0 Then
MkDir (sFileCheck)
End If

If iLength2 = 0 Then
MkDir (sBuildHist)
End If

'Save Master Workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=filePath,

FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
```

The file I am trying to save over is also a .xlsm file.
I've tried removing all charts.
I've tried re-saving the master file.

<sub>It's worth noting that the same day this started happening, my VPN access would not log in until our systems administrator unlocked it (which was a first)</sub>

Comment: Can you connect to the mapped drive via Windows Explorer while on VPN?

Comment: Yes I can connect and open the file just fine on VPN.